# How to keep track of number of messages pulled by node-rdkafka consumer

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I have recently joined a team which uses node-rdkafka in node.js environment. Now I am working on separating the consumer to support so called low priority and high priority topics. The content of the message are the same just need a way to separate the messages into two topics for priority purpose.

I have done with the refactoring so the consumer is now able to support more than instances with each instance subscribe to one topic. Now the remaining issue is to make sure the high priority topic messages are consumed first and then the low priority one. Surprisingly I can't seem to find a consumer method to let me know easily whether or not there are still messages in the topic queue which are not processed. I need something like poll() to return the number of messages the consumer to consume and if nothing returned, I know there is no messages for that topic and I can switch to the low priority topic.

My question: how we can keep track of the topic queue status in node-rdkafa as the similar consume() method doesn't tell me how many messages actually retrieved?

Answer (score 1):

The consumer has a current offset position per partition, and you can [query the high watermark](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/librdkafka/html/rdkafka_8h.html#a4550ff7d014f08406666124573f70495) of each partition.

That difference will give you the consumer lag, which you can keep repeating the query to find how many records are left in each partition, for any topic.

Keep in mind that the consumer closing and recreate to read "other topic" may cause a rebalance event, and every time you hit "zero lag", that's going to ultimately slow down the consumer quite a bit.

> doesn't tell me how many messages actually retrieved

It can, if you just count them - https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/blob/master/test/kafka-consumer-stream.spec.js#L169

Comment: I actually implemented something this way: 1. Create separate instances for each topic. 2. Instead of counting and trying to figure out if there are messages in each topic, keep a queue for each topic, loop through topics in order of priority and if there are messages in the higher priority queue, avoid consuming messages from lower priority topics until the queue of the higher priority topic is drained.